# k8s create ephemeral copies of a pod

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, kustomize

I'd like to create a copy of a k8s pod on the fly,
and patch it with some custom configurations.

Unfortunately,
I don't really know where to start from...

```
  my-service
    - kustomization.yaml
    - deployment.yaml
```

And then

```
kubectl apply -k ./path/to/my-service --override `{ "image": "foo-1", "name": "foo-1" }`
```

the override I am talking about should supply dynamic informations to the deployment,
such as info I only have at build time, etc.

---

#### A.C

- [ ] The original `my-service` pod should not be changed, the *on-the-fly-deployment* should create a new, ephemeral, pod.
- [ ] The new ephemeral pod should have all the informations from the `original`

Comment: Have you considered using [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple base and overlay:

```
my-service/
  base/
    kustomization.yml
    deployment.yml
  overlays/
    ephemeral/
      kustomization.yml
```

`my-service/base/kustomization.yml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - deployment.yml
```

If you don't need a specific name for the ephemeral deployment:

`my-service/overlays/ephemeral/kustomization.yml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../../base

nameSuffix: '-ephemeral'

images:
  - name: myImage
    newName: foo-1

replicas:
  - name: my-deployment
    count: 1
```

If you need a specific name you will have to patch the name in `my-service/overlays/ephemeral/kustomization.yml`.
You can then run:

```sh
kubectl apply -k my-service/base
kubectl apply -k my-service/overlays/ephemeral
```

To be clear, this will create two deployments: the original and one deployment of a single pod. Not one deployment and one lone pod.